# Magento: How to Change default catalog list mode only for tagged collections?

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

A 1.5 store uses catalog list mode "Grid (default)/List", but I need collections of items tagged displayed* using "List (default)/Grid".

It would be nice to enable the different list mode only for specific tag IDs, but I can **consider the task complete done even if I enable this when any tag ID is displayed.**

> Just to make it clear, I am reffering to catalog view thru the
>   `/tag/product/list/tagId/#/ URL`

What is the easiest way to accomplish this? I am using a third party theme.

Answer (score 1):

As for tagged product listing page the template file is catalog/product/list.phtml, 
so first make a copy of catalog/product/list.phtml as catalog/product/list_tagged.phtml.

Now Edit your list_tagged.phtml and insert following line of code just below the "$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');" around line 36.

```
$this->getChild('toolbar')->setCurrentMode('list');
// this will set your default mode to list mode
```

Now your need to edit your tag.xml layout file and set the template file list_tagged.phtml for product listing block.

Hopes this will work.

Answer (score 1):

In your list.phtml you can check to see if you are on a tag page by doing

```
 if(Mage::registry('current_tag'))
```

or check the controller name

```
<?php Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getControllerName(); ?>
```